Rust Compiller maybe bugged
An error occurs at a very simple place. When a reference enters a for loop, there is an implicit conversion to into_iter() on a mutable reference, and as we know, this also implicitly uses the iterator std::slice::IterMut. According to the rules of ownership and borrowing, it is IMPOSSIBLE for the compiler to transfer ownership through a mutable reference, yet this happens. Perhaps there is something I don’t know—can anyone explain?
fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let link = &mut vec;
    for val in link {
        println!("{}", val);
    }
    println!("{:?}", link);
}
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `link`
   --> src\main.rs:7:22
    |
3   |     let link = &mut vec;
    |         ---- move occurs because `link` has type `&mut Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
4   |     for val in link {
    |                ---- `link` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`
7   |     println!("{:?}", link);
    |                      ^^^^ value borrowed here after move
    |
note: `into_iter` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `link`
   --> C:\Users\Aqura\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\core\src\iter\traits\collect.rs:311:18
    |
311 |     fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter;
    |                  ^^^^
    = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` which comes from the expansion of the macro `println` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider creating a fresh reborrow of `link` here
    |
4   |     for val in &mut *link {
    |                ++++++```



When passed through to the body of the loop via &mut *link, everything works. After all, a copy of the link is simply transmitted.

"it is IMPOSSIBLE for the compiler to transfer ownership through a mutable reference" - the underlying vector is not being transferred, it is the mutable reference itself being transferred. Usually the compiler handles reborrows transparently so that mutable references are easier to use, but as the linked answer(s) state that doesn't always happen.
